# C# EntityFramework saving 1-1 relation

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I have a one-to-one relationship between the `Employee` and `EmployeePermission` entities with navigation properties `PermissionTo` and `Employee` respectively. I can load the navigation properties fine, but the problem I'm having is that when I change properties on the related entity `EmployeePermission`, attach the `Employee` entity to a database context and call the `SaveChanges()` method, the changes in the `EmployeePermission` entity are not being persisted to the database, but the changes in the `Employee` entity are.

Here's what my model looks like:

[image: Model]

Here's what my save function looks like:

```
public static void SaveEntities(List<TEntity> entities)
{
    using(var db = GetContext())
    {
        ObjectSet<TEntity> table = db.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        foreach(TEntity entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity.IsNew())
                table.AddObject(entity);
            else
            {
                table.Attach(entity);
                EntityState state = (entity.EntityKey.IsTemporary) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                table.Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, state);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`IsNew()` is an extension method I added to the `EntityObject` class to check if the Entity has to be added or attached to the `EntitySet`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a value indicating if the entity object is new.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entity"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsNew(this EntityObject entity)
{
    return (entity.EntityKey == null || entity.EntityKey.IsTemporary);
}
```

I load an employee and bind its properties on a form, change them and call the `SaveEntities()` method. All the changes to the `Employee` entity are saved to the database, but the changes to the `EmployeePermission` entity are not saved to the database, and I haven't gotten to the other entities yet.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and have been searching for hours. I appreciate all the help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like you've changed the `EmployeePermission` record since you added it to the context. Since the EF doesn't know it's modified, it's unaware there's anything to save. You can call `ChangeObjectState` on that object, as well, if you care to.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Can you show me an example? And what if I have one-to-many relationships (which I will later), will I have to do this method on each related entity? Seems tedious.

Comment: It's tedious because you've chosen to bind directly to disconnected entities instead of using view models and updating attached entities.